# Asynchronously Write Large Array of Objects to Redis with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I created a Node.js script that creates a large array of randomly generated test data and I want to write it to a Redis DB. I am using the [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) client library and the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library. Initially, I tried executing a `redisClient.hset(...)` command within the `for` loop that generates my test data, but after some Googling, I learned the Redis method is asynchronous while the `for` loop is synchronous. After seeing some questions on StackOverflow, I can't get it to work the way I want.

I can write to Redis without a problem with a small array or larger, such as one with 100,000 items.  However, it does not work well when I have an array of 5,000,000 items.  I end up not having enough memory because the redis commands seem to be queueing up, but aren't executed until after `async.each(...)` is complete and the node process does not exit.  How do I get the Redis client to actually execute the commands, as I call `redisClient.hset(...)`?

Here a fragment of the code I am working with.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var async = require('async');

var redisClient = redis.createClient(6379, '192.168.1.150');

var testData = generateTestData();

async.each(testData, function(item, callback) {

    var someData = JSON.stringify(item.data);

    redisClient.hset('item:'+item.key, 'hashKey', someData, function(err, reply) {
        console.log("Item was persisted.  Result: " +reply);
    });

    callback();
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log.info("Items have been persisted to Redis.");

    }
});
```

Comment: What happens if you use eachSeries or eachLimit instead?

Comment: Wait until the callback fires to do more items?

Comment: @SpiderPig - I get the following error - ```buffer.js:634
  return !(val & 0x80) ? val : (0xff - val + 1) * -1;
           ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.isBuffer (util.js:586:25)
    at Function.isBuffer (buffer.js:160:15)
    at RedisClient.send_command ```

@bjb568 - How do I wait until the callback fires?

Comment: Would you be open to a solution using promises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call eachLimit to ensure you are not executing too many redisClient.hset calls at the same time.
To avoid overflowing the call stack you could do `setTimeout(callback, 0);` instead of calling the callback directly.

edit:

Forget what I said about setTimeout. All you need to do is call the callback at the right place. Like so:

```
redisClient.hset('item:'+item.key, 'hashKey', someData, function(err, reply) {
    console.log("Item was persisted.  Result: " +reply);
    callback();
});
```

You may still want to use eachLimit and try out which limit works best.

By the way - async.each is supposed to be used only on code that schedules the invocation of the callback in the javascript event queue (e.g. timer, network, etc) . Never use it on code that calls the callback immediately as was the case in your original code.

edit:

You can implement your own eachLimit function that instead of an array takes a generator as it's first argument. Then you write a generator function to create the test data. For that to work, node needs to be run with "node --harmony code.js".

```
function eachLimit(generator, limit, iterator, callback) {
  var isError = false, j;

  function startNextSetOfActions() {
    var elems = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      j = generator.next();
      if(j.done) break;
      elems.push(j.value);
    }
    var activeActions = elems.length;

    if(activeActions === 0) {
      callback(null);
    }

    elems.forEach(function(elem) {
      iterator(elem, function(err) {
        if(isError) return;
        else if(err) {
          callback(err);
          isError = true;
          return;
        }
        activeActions--;
        if(activeActions === 0) startNextSetOfActions();
      });
    });
  }

  startNextSetOfActions();
}

function* testData() {
  while(...) {
    yield new Data(...);
  }
}

eachLimit(testData(), 10, function(item, callback) {
    var someData = JSON.stringify(item.data);

    redisClient.hset('item:'+item.key, 'hashKey', someData, function(err, reply) {
        if(err) callback(err);
        else {
          console.log("Item was persisted.  Result: " +reply);
          callback();
        }
    });
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log.info("Items have been persisted to Redis.");

    }
});
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!  How can I call `redisClient.hset(...)` inside the `for` loop, so I don't have to store all the data in memory, then write to Redis?

Comment: Using a generator function would be an interesting solution to that.